Display local image in streamlit using components.html
I want to display a local image in streamlit app using components.html. But it is not geting displayed.
Following is code I am using:
import streamlit as st
import base64

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

import streamlit.components.v1 as components

file_ = open("mathsisfun.png", "rb")
contents = file_.read()
data_url = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
file_.close()


components.html(
    """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        function loadImg(dataUrl)
        {
            document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + data_url;
        }
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Image</title>
</head>
<body onload="loadImg(dataUrl)">
    <img id="ItemPreview" src="">
</body>
</html> 

    """,
    height=200,
)

How to use the byte data "data_url" in components.html() code?

why not use st.image() ?

That's because there is an uncaught ReferenceError (that you can view with CTRL+SHIFT+I):
Uncaught ReferenceError: dataUrl is not defined
    at onload (about:srcdoc:14:41)

You can fix it by using the correct variable's name & f-strings :
components.html(
f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <script>
         function loadImg(data_url)
         {{
         var itemPrev = document.getElementById("ItemPreview");
         itemPrev.src = "data:image/png;base64," + data_url;
         }}
      </script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Test Image</title>
   </head>
   <body onload="loadImg('{data_url}')">
      <img id="ItemPreview" src="">
   </body>
</html>
""",
    height=200,
)

NB: There is no need for JavaScript here. You can use plain HTML (see full code).


Thanks, the correct variable's name & f-strings solved the issue !

yes, javascript is not required, it works with plain html as you have shown in the code. Thanks !!


You have to fix your JS:

document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + data_url;
in function(dataUrl) you use camelCase, so using snake_case causes you an error.
document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + dataUrl;

You can use this:
<body onload="loadImg(""" + data_url + """)"> to insert your phyton string into JS.

EDIT:
Using format data like at the other answer seems more elegant to me.

ya, formatted string works here.
